# When I hide all unused Rows the spreadsheet becomes very slow

Tags: excel

Ok, so a weird question, I have a spreadsheet I am trying to format to make it look more appealing to use. One of the things I want to do is hide all unused rows and columns. Which ofc is an easy enough task, and when I hide the columns I have no problems.

However when I hide the rows on my spreadsheet it starts to become very slow and laggy. At the same time the column containing the row numbers gets wider, which I find odd. The sheet does have a lot of comments in it as well which I guess might not be helping?

I was wondering if anyone had came across this issue before and knew what was causing / a work around for it?

Many thanks

Darren

Comment: Are the hidden rows blank? If so, why aren't they being deleted?

Comment: @guitarthrower I mean they are empty, is there a way to delete rows in excel to get the same effect as hiding them?

Comment: Sort all rows, then delete all empty rows (which should then be at the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Before you attempt to hide or show the rows add:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

When you are done hiding or showing the rows, make sure to add:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Excel 2007 or newer? 
We are heavy users of Excel at my work, and we have encountered this. As far as I can tell, there is no work around for this. It slows down because between Excel 2003 (in which you could this and it would NOT be slow) to Excel 2007, they increased the row limit to 1 million rows. So when you are hiding 900,000 rows, it just seems to slow it down (as opposed to like, 50,000 in 2003). 
I think your best bet is to just accept that you will be seeing blank rows in your file.

Comment: Yea its Excel 2007, i feared this may be the case. I assume that when you hide rows excel starts taking them into account however when they are not hidden they are somewhat ignored. Or at least that is the only logic that works for me. Once you add in my macros and editing i guess it just becomes laggy. Thought I would throw it out to the community to make sure i wasnt the only one who experienced it at the very least. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cells which you are hiding are not completely empty (they might contain invisible information). When cells are hidden in plain view Excel still tries to render them, unless they are outside the used range. 
By the way, this also explains why the column containing the row numbers gets wider. It grows to fit the larger row numbers.

Make all rows visible and press ctrl-end. This will jump to the last row which contains information according to Excel. You'll see is not the row which you expected, maybe even the very last row. Delete all rows below the one which really contains your data. Then SAVE the file (saving will reset the internal "used range"). With Excel 2003 or lower, you'll also have to close and re-open the workbook.

Now you can hide the rows again and it should be fresh and responsive.

If this didn't fix it, the "used range" is bugged. In that case, the only solution which I know of is to cut and paste all rows into a fresh sheet. (make sure you only cut the rows you need, but not the entire sheet, or else you'll copy the bug as well).